# Declined flag "Not an answer"

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I got a "Not an answer" flag declined, although I acted in accordance with the flag description, which at this time is:

> not an answer
>
> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. [..]

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499473/return-a-string-of-n-spaces/62499510#62499510)

The question clearly asks for a specific technicality (to use a while loop), but at the time of flagging the answer was completely oblivious to this. Therefore, I made the judgement that the answer did not make an attempt to answer the specific question at hand. Hence I raised the corresponding flag.

I'm aware that the answer at the time of flagging tried to provide a solution to the perceived problem. It appears likely that the answerer was not fully aware of the requirements posed by the OP.

For the above reasons I believe the flag to be raised appropiately.

Comment: I think they keyword there is **attempt**. It will make sense if you read [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552).

Comment: All revisions of that answer are an answer. Raising an NAA was never the right option. I know this is confusing but there is a typo in that flag description. Read it as "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer **a** question. [..]"

Comment: @rene That's the thing. I read it carefully, and I acted according to the words I read in the official markup..

Comment: Then there is still no guarantee you flag gets accepted. No matter how "right' you are.

Comment: The "Not an answer" flag is for things that are either complete gibberish and as such cannot even attempt to answer anything because they are just incoherent. *Or* it's something that is comprehensible yet not even barely an answer - "Thank you", or "I have this problem too", or something that would have been a comment "What version of X are you using?", or perhaps a completely different question "How do I do Y?". An answer that is *incorrect* either in the interpretation of the question or even in terms of implementation is still *an answer* and shouldn't be flagged. You *can* downvote those.

Comment: @VLAZ "The "Not an answer" flag is for things that are either complete gibberish and as such cannot even attempt to answer anything because they are just incoherent" that's interesting, because [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/213575) refers that things that look like an apple (answer) but isn't an apple when the person is asking for apples (the question) it's NAA.

Comment: @Braiam I honestly never understood the pictures because I can never map them to actual posts. I'm stating my understanding based on other discussions as well as how some of my flags were handled.

Comment: @VLAZ This comment goes into more detail https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer#comment894439_225370

Comment: @Braiam my earlier flagging decline rate is tells me otherwise. As much as I would love to be able to flag answers that aren't directly addressing a question, I can't. I *tried it* and was denied. All I can do is do my best to actually answer the question. Often a person post their code and asks why it doesn't work and then answers pour in with *other* solutions, rather than explaining why the original was wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @VLAZ One way you don't get denied is by not accepting the _status quo_. If you see a question like this one just say: SO got the strange idea that you don't deleted "attempts to answer a question" even if it's not the question asked. That way you are pointing out how bizarre of SO compared to other sites. That is also why I engaged to your comment, to [prevent situations like this](http://i.snag.gy/kdu77.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

All revisions of that answer, from the first to the latest contain an attempt to answer a question, with a bit of luck even the question.

For that reason alone, raising an Not An Answer flag is the wrong moderation action.

Keep in mind that reviewers primarily look at the post, in this case an answer, in isolation. It isn't guaranteed that a reviewer will look at a wider context if they are not triggered to do so. A comment and the stronger signal, a down vote, might have triggered reviewers to look a bit further but then they might still decide that the answer is an an answer and shouldn't be deleted.

See also [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer?rq=1)

Use downvotes for actual answers that don't answer **the** question.

Comment: "Keep in mind that reviewers primarily look at the post, in this case an answer, in isolation" put me out of that group. The question is bellow the answer when reviewing in the queue. I think you are confusing the moderator queue to the LQRQ.

Comment: @Braiam I've moved you out that group.

Comment: @rene disappointed I didn't read *"Keep in mind that reviewers primarily look at the post, in this case an answer, in isolation* ***(except Braiam)*** *"* in the post after reading that comment...

Comment: This answer assumes wide knowledge of the do's and don'ts on SO. Therefore, I believe the real answer to be: don't ever rely on a piece of description markup that you find on SO, but first spend an undefined amount of time on meta.

Comment: @snwflk no problem, I'm glad my answer brought you that insight.